# How can I replace"span3" to "col3" without changing the "span"?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

```
<span class="span3"></span><span class="span4"></span>
<span class="span5"></span><span class="span6"></span>
```

to

```
<span class="col3"></span><span class="col4"></span>
<span class="col5"></span><span class="col6"></span>
```

How can I replace `span*` to `col*` without changing the `span`?

Edit 1:
My question here is how to convert `span3` to `col3` without changing `span`, cause I don't know `\1` or `$1` when I was a newbie to regular expression. The solution for me at that time was to replace `span` to `col`, which will affect `span`, too.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: My bet is on Java.  Someone else want to try for .NET :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Let's add solutions for all the different languages then ;-)

Comment: From [tag:regex] tag: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: It's ST3.Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a simple find and replace.  Capture the number of the CSS class in parentheses, and then replace using this capture group.

```
Find:    class="span(\d)"
Replace: class="col\1"
```

Comment: I'm so sorry cause I didn't make my question clearly.Thanks anyway:-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Id attribute to your span tag. For example:

```
<span class="span3" id="myspan"></span>
```

Next, using JavaScript or similar (the example I include is JavaScript) you can replace with these two lines:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myspan");
elem.setAttribute('class',"col3");
```

Comment: I'm so sorry cause I didn't make my question clearly.Thanks anyway:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery, use method switchClass().

```
$("span.span3").switchClass('span3', 'col3');
```

Comment: I'm so sorry cause I didn't make my question clearly.I want to do this on ST3.Thanks anyway:-)